# More input to LSTM

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm not sure how to feed a data to LSTM, where I have 6 columns with relation. I was using a model designed for one input and tried to change the dimensions. First I added

`nsamples, nx, ny = X_train.shape`

`X_train = X_train.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))`

To make sure that `MixMaxScaler` takes the data in two dimensions. The model was using three dimesions for LSTM (last one was `1`), so I reshaped it to `6` and fed it to the model. But it throws an error:
`Error when checking target: expected dense to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (69692, 42, 6)`
So I've added `flatten` layer. It doesn't help... What I'm doing wrong? 
Btw. 7 means 7 days prediction.
My Data looks like this
[image]

And here is the code

```py
data_test = (data.loc['2014-01-01':,:])
data_train = data.loc[:'2013-12-31', :]

data_train = np.array(data_train)

X_train, y_train = [], []

for i in range(7, len(data_train)-7):
    X_train.append(data_train[i-7:i])
    y_train.append(data_train[i:i+7])

X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

nsamples, nx, ny = X_train.shape
X_train = X_train.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))

nsamples, nx, ny = y_train.shape
y_train = y_train.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))


x_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = x_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
y_train = y_scaler.fit_transform(y_train)
print(X_train, y_train)

# >>>69692, 42 / 69692, 42


X_train = X_train.reshape(69692, 7, 6)
y_train = y_train.reshape(69692, 7, 6)

reg = Sequential()
reg.add(LSTM(units = 200, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(7,6)))
reg.Flatten()
reg.add(Dense(7))
reg.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
reg.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100)



X_test, y_test = [], []
data_test = np.array(data_test)

for i in range(7, len(data_test)-7):
    X_test.append(data_test[i-7:i])
    y_test.append(data_test[i:i+7])



X_test, y_test = np.array(X_test), np.array(y_test)

nsamples, nx, ny = X_test.shape
X_test = X_test.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))

nsamples, nx, ny = y_test.shape
y_test = y_test.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))

X_test = x_scaler.transform(X_test)
y_test = y_scaler.transform(y_test)
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
# >>> 12189, 42 / 12189, 42

X_test = X_test.reshape(12189,7,6)

y_pred = reg.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Can you try something like reg.add(LSTM(200, input_dim=1)) and remove Flatten layer?

Comment: thanks for the reply; It throws `TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'input_dim')
`

Comment: Apologies for wrong suggestion. I was looking at some github implementations and thus suggested you this param. Looks like this param is not available in LSTM layer now.

Comment: try `input_shape` instead of `input_dim`

Comment: input_shape=(1)? Throws: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

Your code has this as Flatten:
`reg.Flatten()`

Try this instead:
`reg.add(Flatten())`

**EDIT:**

I have tried the code similar to yours below, and it worked. I'm not sure why your Y has shape of (7,6). Try to understand how my code is **conceptually** different from yours (especially your target output Y).

```
X_train = np.array([[6.8, 36.3,140.1,31,3.2,4],[7.6, 40.5, 141.4,0,4.6,5]])
X_train = X_train.reshape(2,3,2)
Y_train = np.array([[1],[3]])

reg = Sequential()
reg.add(LSTM(units = 200, activation = 'relu', input_shape=                        
(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
reg.add(Flatten())
reg.add(Dense(1))
reg.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
#reg.summary()
reg.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 100)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I added `reg.add(Flatten())` Throws: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (69692, 7, 6)`

Comment: but when I comment-out that `Dense`, it throws `Error when checking target: expected flatten to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (69692, 7, 6)`

Comment: Thanks for the code! It works, but I would like to ask one thing. I'm using the loop there to make the data in chunk of 7 (day), so I predict day 8 at the base of 7 days. But when I `shape` your code it shows (n rows, 6 columns). There is not that 7 days chunk what I was using, is it impossible to use it like that? I was using this base 

https://github.com/laxmimerit/Multi-Step-Time-Series-Prediction-using-RNN-LSTM-for-household-power-consumption/blob/master/Household%20Power%20Consumption%20Prediction%20using%20RNN%20LSTM%20(1).ipynb